# Can someone undelete my question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I deleted it because I couldn't reproduce the error so I assume I fixed it but I'm having the error again.

I can't even find the link to my question (it was about out-of-gas and MetaMask)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look on your profile, under [questions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/4832/teleporting-goat?tab=questions), you should see [deleted recent questions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/4832), as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13203/238332).

(assuming I got the link right for you, can't test that).